# Why doesn't Character.toString give the error The method toString() in the type Object is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Tags: java, string, character

I was working with characters in Java and I was converting a integer to a character string. I had copied some code from another project, where I was not getting the error, and pasted it into my current project. When I ran the code and I kept getting the same, The method toString() in the type Object is not applicable for the arguments (int), error. Why do I get this error in only one project and how can I fix it?

Here's my code:

```
public class main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int num = 115;
       String value = Character.toString(num); //<-- Error here
       System.out.println(value);
   }
}
```

Comment: `Character.toString()` accepts a `char` as a parameter, but you passed an `int` to it.  https://www.javatpoint.com/post/java-character-tostring-method

Comment: An `int` overload was added in a later version.

Comment: I tried with char to

Comment: @RobertHarvey this can be made to work with 115 (by writing `"" + (char) 115`) - but what if the OP wanted to use 128512 - the code point for ? With `Character.toString(int)` even this is allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [`Character.toString(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#toString(int)) introduced in Java 11, it accepts a code point. In other words, you're probably using Java 11 or higher in one project, and not in the other, or you're compiling against `-release 8` or another version below 11.

As an aside, you say you're *"converting a integer to a character string"*. That is not what `Character.toString(int)` does (it converts an integer Unicode code point to a one or two character string representing that codepoint). If you want to convert an integer to string, use [`Integer.toString(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#toString(int)) or [`String.valueOf(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(int)).